# Sort values greater than zero using large function

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table with multiple columns. The columns have positive, zero and negative values:

2000

-3000

4000

0

-6000

8000

How can I sort values which are greater than zero? The result should look like:

8000

4000

2000

I was playing with this code:

For i = 1 To 4

```
  .Cells(36 + i, 3) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(.Range("A1:D10"), 1 + i - 1)
```

Next i

Comment: Do you want the negative values discarded??

Comment: @Gary: I want to discard zero and negative values. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will sort your #'s (in range C1:C100) in decending order:

```
Sub Sort_column_C()
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C1:C100"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("C1:C100")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Thanks Mike. Sort function is limited to column sorting only that's why I am using Large function.